# Android Error: SDK23 v SDK19 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

My Android app uses Google Maps and compiles fine for both an SDK23 and SDK19 device.  It runs fine on the SDK23 (LG G4) but generates this error SDK19 device (Samsung Galaxy 4) => java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.android.gms.R$string

These are my dependencies:
[Android Studio Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1yqR.jpg)

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.volkerpetersen.sailingrace">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"></uses-feature>

<application
    android:name=".GlobalParameters"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".start_timerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_timer"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="com.example.volkerpetersen.sailingrace.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".start_raceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_race"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.volkerpetersen.sailingrace.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".start_mapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_map"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.volkerpetersen.sailingrace.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SailingRacePreferences"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.volkerpetersen.sailingrace.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SailTimerAPI"></receiver>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource using the <meta-data> tag
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDzCAa-hibdRJ-NdOnIRK-IG5uN2U3kv9c" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- original code replaced with above
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    -->

</application>
```

When I searched for this error I couldn't find a solution/answer why my app compiles/runs fine under SDK23, but generates this run-time error under SDK19.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem.

I needed to downgraded the Manifest from 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
to the older version 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' to ensure compatibility with the device software on both devices.

The App now runs on the SDK19 and SDK23 phone.  Thanks Mounir for pointing me in the right direction.  Much appreciated!

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help. please mark your answer as the correct answer to help other.

Answer (score 0):

please try to clean your project, and then remove from your App Gradle the 2 last dependencies: play-services gcm an identities

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  It got me a step further.  
The app now launches, but I now get an error msg when I try to launch the map fragment.  Error msg:  "GooglePlayServiceUtil: Google Play service out of date.  Requires 848700 but found 8301038".

 Any help of this?

Comment: what is your target sdk? please show you build.gradle for your App Module